The real world implementations of RAG vs the methods explained in the paper
While building a RAG application we

Encode the query
Retrieve k docs
Concatenate before the query
Pass the entire thing to a LLM and it completes it for you

I do not think this is either of RAG-sequence or RAG-token explained in the paper. Or, am I missing something. It seems closer to RAG-sequence but there also there are k output sequences generated which are then marginalized over the retrieved documents and the output sequence with the highest probability is selected
From the paper:

RAG-Sequence Model The RAG-Sequence model uses the same retrieved document to generate
the complete sequence. Technically, it treats the retrieved document as a single latent variable that
is marginalized to get the seq2seq probability p(y|x) via a top-K approximation. Concretely, the
top K documents are retrieved using the retriever, and the generator produces the output sequence
probability for each document, which are then marginalized,


RAG-Token Model In the RAG-Token model we can draw a different latent document for each
target token and marginalize accordingly. This allows the generator to choose content from several
documents when producing an answer. Concretely, the top K documents are retrieved using the
retriever, and then the generator produces a distribution for the next output token for each document,
before marginalizing, and repeating the process with the following output token

